# How can I use a code ref as a callback in Perl?

Tags: perl, reference, scripting, callback

I have the following code in my class :

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my %args  = @_;
    my $self  = {};
    bless( $self, $class );
    if ( exists $args{callback} ) {
        $self->{callback} = $args{callback};
    }
    if ( exists $args{dir} ) {
        $self->{dir} = $args{dir};
    }
    return $self;
}

sub test {
  my $self = shift;
  my $arg  = shift;
  &$self->{callback}($arg);
}
```

and a script containing the following code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyPackage;

my $callback = sub {
   my $arg = shift;
   print $arg;
};

my $obj = MyPackage->new(callback => $callback);
```

but I receive the following error:

```
Not a CODE reference ...
```

What am I missing? Printing `ref($self->{callback})` shows `CODE`. It works if I use `$self->{callback}->($arg)`, but I would like to use another way of invoking the code ref.

Comment: Why do you want another way to dereference a code ref? Use what works and move on to the next problem. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The ampersand is binding just to `$self` and not the whole thing. You can do curlies around the part that returns the reference:

```
&{$self->{callback}}($arg);
```

But the

```
$self->{callback}->($arg);
```

is generally considered cleaner, why don't you want to use it?

Comment: My perl is kinda rusty. I knew I was missing something , and I wanted to find out what that was :). Thank you Adam !